# Grouping Objects in Java

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, swingx

Is there any way to group objects in Java core SE ?

Like i have multiple JButtons, JLabels and other objects and i want to set the visibility of them to false and enable using a function.

Can i group these Java objects as a single unit so that i do not have to write each `component.setVisiiblity(true)` like this.

For further example i have something like this:

```
private void hideDashboard() {
    someButton1.setVisible(false);
    someButton2.setVisible(false);
    someButton3.setVisible(false);
    someButton4.setVisible(false);
    someLabel.setVisible(false);
}
```

I am not using any external packages. For IDE i am using Netbeans 8.2

Comment: You could put them into a collection (such as `List<JComponent> dashBoardComponents`), iterate it and call `setVisible(false)` on each element.

Comment: You can also place them on their own separate JPanel and hide/show that panel.

Answer (score 2):

One option would be to store them in a Collection since they're all JComponent objects.

```java
Collection<JComponent> components = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(button1, button2, button3, button4, button5));

components.forEach(component -> component.setVisible(false));
```

Comment: `Arrays.asList` already returns a list. We don't need to wrap it in `new ArrayList<>(...)` unless we want to modify that list later.

Comment: Yeah, which is what I assume OP wants to do. Wanted to avoid; **But now I cant add components to it**.

Comment: Thank you very much . Collection class was all i needed to find.

Comment: Can new component be added dynamically to this list ? if Yes , then how ?

Comment: Haha, what did I say? :P @Pshemo. Yes you can simply add new components to this Collection by calling components.add(component) where component is your JComponent object.

Comment: I may be misunderstood. Purpose of my previous comment wasn't to state that there is some problem in the answer, but to state that `Arrays.asList` may be enough "*..unless we want to modify that list later*". Happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the same approach when showing/hiding elements in HTML. You can wrap them with a parent element(e.g. div) and show/hide them using CSS(e.g. display: none).

As with Java, if I am not mistaken, if you add child panels to a parent panel and you show/hide the parent panel, the child panels will also be simply shown/hidden.

Answer (score 0):

And there are some other options also:

1. If you want to just make invisible some components you can add them in a `CardLayout` with a panel containing all of them and a blank one.
2. If you want to apply an action to a `Container` (such as a `JComponent`) and all of its children `Component`s, then you can make a recursive routine to do that (well actually it is not necessary obviously to be recursive, but that would have a more *obvious* code in my opinion).

Code for first option:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.CardLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JCheckBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;

public class Grouping1 {

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        final JPanel buttons = new JPanel();
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
            buttons.add(new JButton("Does nothing " + i));

        final JPanel internal = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        internal.add(new JTextArea("1234567890.\n0987654321."), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        internal.add(buttons, BorderLayout.LINE_END);

        final CardLayout clm = new CardLayout();
        final JPanel clp = new JPanel(clm);

        final JCheckBox enable = new JCheckBox("Click me", true);
        enable.addActionListener(e -> clm.show(clp, enable.isSelected()? "FILLED": "BLANK"));

        clp.add(internal, "FILLED");
        clp.add(new JPanel(), "BLANK");

        clm.show(clp, "FILLED");

        final JPanel contents = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        contents.add(clp, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        contents.add(enable, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);

        final JFrame frame = new JFrame("Components");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(contents);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

And code for second option:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.util.function.Consumer;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JCheckBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;

public class Grouping2 {

    public static void applyRecursively(final Container container,
                                        final Consumer<Component> consumer) {
        for (final Component child: container.getComponents())
            if (child instanceof Container)
                applyRecursively((Container) child, consumer);
            else
                consumer.accept(child);
        consumer.accept(container);
    }

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        final JPanel buttons = new JPanel();
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
            buttons.add(new JButton("Does nothing " + i));

        final JPanel internal = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        internal.add(new JTextArea("1234567890.\n0987654321."), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        internal.add(buttons, BorderLayout.LINE_END);

        final JCheckBox enable = new JCheckBox("Click me", true);
        enable.addActionListener(e -> applyRecursively(internal, c -> c.setEnabled(enable.isSelected())));

        final JPanel contents = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        contents.add(internal, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        contents.add(enable, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);

        final JFrame frame = new JFrame("Components");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(contents);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

In both codes, just click the "*Click me*" checkbox to toggle the components' state.

The most precise answer though in my opinion could be Jason's which lets you group the components you are free to select. Having your own `Collection` of `Component`s lets you apply actions to them, without having to be in the same GUI area (as in my first code) and without having to apply to all of the `Container`'s children the action (as in my second code). I guess it depends on your needs.